# How to use Single AWS IoT connection for all component in angular 6

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, iot

I was using AWS IoT for chat and notification purposes in an angular 6 Project. It was working fine but I am connecting from header Component, Chat Component, Home Component for different usage. Instead of connecting from all components, can I to use the connection from header component?

```
aws-sdk
```

When I make a connection each time, I get this error:

```
onConnectionLost: {errorCode: 8, errorMessage: "AMQJS0008I Socket closed."}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**create a shared service**

Connect to `IOT` in shared service, once message arrived assign the received JSON to a variable... then subscribe from your component

**shared.service.ts**

```
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

//variable declare
public msg: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

myFunction(){
     //assign variable
     this.msg.next(message.payloadString);
}
```

**myComponent.component.ts**

```
this.dataSharingService.msg.subscribe((value) => {
  console.log(value);
});
```